# What exactly does 'Include In Project' and 'Exclude From Project' mean in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm looking for some clarity on Visual Studio include and exclude from project flags. Does it simply mean that the file/folder will be included at build time? I'm referring to static assets rather than `.cs` files.

Comment: Yes.  Click the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer toolbar to make more sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This refers to the files which will be explicitly included in your project's `.csproj` file. This is more visible with code files impacting what is included/excluded when building, but it also can impact what files are copied to an output folder, etc. See [Understanding the project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file#items-and-item-groups) for a deeper dive.

For example, in my Visual Studio Theme project I can include some image assets which will be included in my output directory and my VSIX container:

[image: Midnight Deep solution explorer]

And in my `Midnight-Deep.csproj`:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="midnight_deep_preview.PNG">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="screenshot1.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Also note files within the file directory of your project that aren't included can be viewed anyway in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer pane with the "Show All Files" toggle.